# the datepicker UI stops and the function wont run the second time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ms-access-2010

the front end code is as below

```
 <div id="dvRecWed" style="display: none">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PnlUsrDetails" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Reception Date</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReceptionDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>Reception Time</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlReceptionTime" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txtUsername_TextChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Forenoon">Forenoon</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Afternoon">Afternoon</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="FullDay">Full Day</asp:ListItem>

                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="checkdate" class="checkdate" runat="server" visible="false">
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgstatus" runat="server" Width="17px" Height="17px" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

And my back end code is

```
protected void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlReceptionTime.Text))
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName=@Name", con);
        string selectQuery = "SELECT FunctionTime FROM function WHERE FunctionDate=@FunctionDate AND FunctionTime='FullDay'";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = selectQuery;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", txtReceptionDate.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", ddlReceptionTime.Text);
        OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/cross.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date Unavailable";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/check.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date available";
        }
    }




    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlReceptionTime.Text))
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName=@Name", con);
        string selectQuery = "SELECT FunctionTime FROM function WHERE FunctionDate=@FunctionDate AND FunctionTime=@FunctionTime";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = selectQuery;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDate", txtReceptionDate.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionTime", ddlReceptionTime.Text);
        OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/cross.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date Unavailable";
            lblStatus.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }
        else
        {
            checkdate.Visible = true;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/img/check.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Date Available";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        checkdate.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

so the problem I'm facing here is the code actually runs but that's it after it showed the label i cant click on the date textbox which uses a datepicker UI which wont show the calender after the label appears... and it also disables the js for other datepicker textboxes too that doesnt even concern with these fields
the important problem is it stop the datepicker UIs and this code itself wont run again unless i refresh the page i want to be able to check other available dates if one if not available
... so please help me again... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can not see any datepicker code in your question and assuming you are using the same jquery ui datepicker.

btw you can also use the same below:

```
function jScript() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1950:' + new Date().getFullYear().toString()
            });
        });
    }
```

you have to use datepicker class for textbox like below:

```
<asp:TextBox class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ID="txtdate" CssClass="datepicker"
                                    placeholder="mm/dd/yy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now for initializing the datepicker every time after your page loads, you have to use below code, basically it loads the above function everytime.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(jScript);    
</script>
```

please update your code according to this, may be it helps.

Comment: thank you that has solved my datepicker problem but i still have problem with showing the label you it shows date unavailable once then if select another date thats available then it shows date available no problem until then but after it showed both the labels it doesnt work anymore.... i mean each of the labels load only once so could you please help me with that too? thank you

Comment: In your code both **if**  and  **else if** block are same. please correct and check may be it works.

Comment: yeah both are same except for the query i have to pass 2 queries

Comment: If both are same then when **else if** block will come in execution ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the updatepanel you are using in the form. In this case you have to add following code in master page file.

All jquery which need to be reloaded on Asynchronous postback call, that should be added in following function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $.getScript('MY_UTILITY_SCRIPT.js', function () {
        });
    }
  </script>
```